# Android - Animation with only 2 images and mask

Tags: android, image, animation, mask

I'm trying to make an **animation** with **only 2 images** and using a **mask**. But I do not know how. **I can not use animation-list**. I need help to do so. Thank you.

The effect of the animation would look like this:

[image]

```
public void makeMaskImage(ImageView mImageView, int mContent) {

    Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mContent);
    Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.mask);
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_b);
}
```

**animation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

<translate
    android:duration="3000"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the class of **Nicolas Simon** and code works perfectly

```
public class RevealView extends ImageView {

    private Bitmap secondBitmap;
    private float mAnimationPercentage;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public RevealView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public RevealView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public RevealView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setPercentage(0);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER));
        mPath = new Path();
    }

    public void setPercentage(int p) {
        if(p > 100) {
            p = 100;
        }
        mAnimationPercentage = p / 100f;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Bitmap mRegularBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        if (mRegularBitmap != null && secondBitmap != null) {
            //First draw your regular image
            canvas.drawBitmap(mRegularBitmap, 0, 0, null);

            //Then clip the canvas depending on the animation percentage, using a Path
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo((float) canvas.getWidth() * mAnimationPercentage, 0.0f);
            mPath.lineTo((float) canvas.getWidth() * mAnimationPercentage, canvas.getHeight());
            mPath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            mPath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), 0.0f);
            mPath.close();

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            canvas.clipPath(mPath);

            //Then draw the gray bitmap on top
            canvas.drawBitmap(secondBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
        }
    }

    public void setSecondBitmap(Bitmap secondBitmap) {
        this.secondBitmap = secondBitmap;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    revealView.setSecondBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_1));

    percentage = 0;
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (percentage <= 100) {
                        revealView.setPercentage(percentage);
                        percentage++;
                    } else {
                        cancel();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 120);
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.example.animation.RevealView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img_2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom View for that, to work with the `onDraw` method, and especially the `clip` function.
This class is working for me, but is left very opened to modifications on your side.
An implementation would be as follow :

```
public class RevealView extends View {
private Bitmap                  mRegularBitmap;
private Bitmap                  mGrayScaleBitmap;
private float                   mAnimationPercentage;
private Path                    mPath;
private Paint                   mPaint;

public RevealView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public RevealView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public RevealView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mRegularBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sign_in_up_icon);
    mGrayScaleBitmap = toGrayScale(mRegularBitmap);
    mAnimationPercentage = 0.0f;

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPath = new Path();
}

public void reset() {
    mAnimationPercentage = 0.0f;
}

public void setPercentage(float p) {
    mAnimationPercentage = p;
}

private Bitmap toGrayScale(Bitmap origin) {
    int width, height;
    height = origin.getHeight();
    width = origin.getWidth();

    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);
    c.drawBitmap(origin, 0, 0, paint);
    return (bmpGrayscale);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //First draw your regular image
    canvas.drawBitmap(mRegularBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    //Then clip the canvas depending on the animation percentage, using a Path
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo((float)canvas.getWidth() * mAnimationPercentage, 0.0f);
    mPath.lineTo((float)canvas.getWidth() * mAnimationPercentage, canvas.getHeight());
    mPath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    mPath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), 0.0f);
    mPath.close();

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    canvas.clipPath(mPath);

    //Then draw the gray bitmap on top
    canvas.drawBitmap(mGrayScaleBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
}
```

Then define your own animation, and simply call
`myRevealView.setPercentage(float);`

Depending on the Thread you're calling it, then either use
`myRevealView.invalidate()//main thread` or
`myRevealView.postInvalidate()//background thread`